# How to assign true to a boolean variable in c language

Tags: c, boolean, boolean-expression

I want to assign true to the boolean variable leapYear if the integer variable year is a leap year (A leap year is a multiple of 4, and if it is a multiple of 100, it must also be a multiple of 400.)in a c program

Here's the code I tried.

```
bool leapYear;
int year;

printf("Enter a year ");
scanf("%d", &year);
if (year %4 = 0 || year %100 = 0 || year %400 = 0)
    printf("true");
```

I tried to compile the code I wrote but it gives an error saying unknown type name 'bool'.

Comment: Unreleated to the question: All your `=` should be `==`

Comment: Please `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: Also, your leap year logic is wrong, it returns true for all multiples of 4, it doesn't do the century exceptions correctly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029417/correct-expression-for-checking-leap-years

Comment: Use _Bool inatead

Comment: You never use the variable `leapYear`.

Comment: Use `_Bool` or include `<stdbool.h>` to get the `bool` alias.

Comment: Even if you use `_Bool b = true;` you still need to `#include <stdbool.h>` for the `true` to be accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include the header file `<stdbool.h>`

In this file `bool` is defined as a macro and expands to the C standard unsigned integer type `_Bool`.

Any value that is not equal to `0` is converted to `1` and assigned to a variable of the type _Bool.

To set for example a variable to true You could just write

```
bool leapYear = 1;
```

The header file also contains macros for `true` and `false`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) 
{
    bool leapYear = true;

    printf( "leapYear = %u\n", leapYear );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
leapYear = 1
```

If you do not want to include the header then you could just use the standard integer type `_Bool`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    _Bool leapYear = 1;

    printf( "leapYear = %u\n", leapYear );

    return 0;
}
```

Or even the type `int` like

```
int leapYear = 1;
```

In C logical operations return integer 1 if an expression is true or 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to `#include <stdbool.h>` to use booleans, but in C we usually use an integer. The way it works is 0 is false, anything else is true.

In your case,

```
int leapYear = 0;    // default to false
... 
leapYear = 1;    // set to true. Any non-zero value works.
```

Comment: `bool` *is* a standard type since C99

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry, wrong terminology. What I meant was it is not included by default, you have to include it yourself.

Comment: `_Bool` is a standard type that is available without inclusion of any headers. So still, yes, booleans are "included by default".  They need to be, because `_Bool` has special rules that don't apply to any other type.  `bool` is just an alias for `_Bool`, provided for convenience by stdbool.h.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It is my understanding that using `_Bool` is considered bad practice

Comment: Dunno where you got that idea, @ZacharyOldham.  If anything, I'd be inclined to put it the other way around -- using `bool` in C is potentially problematic because it risks colliding with code that provides its own definition for that symbol, and such code isn't particularly uncommon.  But that's entirely beside the point. `_Bool`s are booleans. The `bool` of stdbool.h is the same type, but you don't need the header to have booleans.  (And `_Bool` *is* an integer.)

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has pointed out, your main problem was failure to `#include <stdbool.h>`. Also, your use of `=` instead of `==` in the conditional. I, personally, would not try to use a single conditional because the rules for leap year are complex and hard to translate into a single statement. I'd use a function for clarity:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_leap(int year) {
    if (0 == (year % 400)) return true;
    if (0 == (year % 100) && year > 1582) return false;
    if (0 == (year % 4)) return true;
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    . . .
    bool leap = is_leap(2019);
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Off by 1. 1700 is often considered a non-leap year [ref](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-years-such-as-1700-1800-1900-not-leap-years-even-though-they-are-divisible-by-4-but-1600-and-2000-are).  Suggest `0 == (year % 100) && year >= 1700` or `0 == (year % 100) && year > 1582`